# Page url not found in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I make this app in django for showing Category in Django. I made the views and the urls app for this feature, but it didn' t work. I don't know why it doesn't work. I have tried a lot of different codes to solve it, but they didn't work.

Urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import 
staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'), #Index
  url(r'^all-articles$', views.PostList, name='PostList'), #All 
Posts
  url(r'^category$', views.Category, name='Category'), #All 
  CAtegory
  path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), 
name='post_detail'), #Single Posts

]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *
from django.views.generic import View
from django.views import generic


def index(request): #HomePage
  return render(request, 'blog/index.php', {})


# Post Section

def PostList(request): #Articles List
  articles = Article.objects.all().order_by('data')
  return render(request, 'blog/post/PostList.php', 
{'articles':articles})

class PostDetail(generic.DetailView): #Single Article
  model = Article
  template_name = 'blog/post/post_detail.php'

def Category(request): #Category List
  category = Category.objects.all()
  return render(request, 'blog/post/category.php', 
{'category':category})
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

#Categorie
class Category(models.Model):
  class Meta:
      verbose_name = 'category'
      verbose_name_plural = 'categorie'

  name = models.CharField('Titolo', max_length = 250)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 250, unique = True)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.name
#Articles
class Article(models.Model):
  class Meta:
      verbose_name = 'Articolo'
      verbose_name_plural = 'Articoli'
  '''
  Classe per creare articoli generali con media
  '''
  title = models.CharField('Titolo', max_length=100)
  author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
  category = models.ForeignKey (Category, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  desc = models.CharField('Descrizione', max_length=10000, 
blank=True)
  text = models.TextField('Testo', max_length=10000, blank=True)
  image = models.ImageField('Foto', blank=True, upload_to="img")
  data = models.DateTimeField('Data di pubblicazione', blank=True)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 250, null = True, blank = 
True, unique=True)

  class Meta: #ordinare i post secondo la data
      ordering = ['-data',]

  def __str__(self):
      return "Crea un nuovo articolo"
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: why are you rendering to `category.php,` it should be `.html` file

Comment: the error is this: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/
Raised by: blog.views.PostDetail
Trovato nessun article corrispondente alla query

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.